# Should we remove all incorrect uses of code?

Tags: discussion, editing, formatting

Since it has been [decided](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6034/should-code-markdown-be-used-for-emphasis) that code markdown shouldn’t be used for text that isn’t code, should we remove all instances of code markdown for text that isn’t code?

In case anybody is interested, there are currently around 530 instances of code on the main and meta sites combined.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that this is necessary.

Editing all of that old content because of a minor formatting inconsistency would just cause unnecessary noise on the frontpage for little tangible benefit. But you can of course do such edits for posts which are already on the frontpage anyway.

Comment: I disagree. Mass retags often happen on MSE (which has similar activity levels to this site), and this is similar in my opinion.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica That's not the same thing. Retagging has a tangible benefit because it makes that content easier to find in the future.

Comment: removing incorrect code formatting has the tangible benefit of making certain text easier to read for some people.

Answer (score 6):

To add on to what was posted by Philipp. I don't think we should worry about editing old posts that haven't had activity in a while if that is the only reason it is going to be edited.

However that being said if you stumble on an older post and are going to make edits to it for other reasons it would be acceptable to also fix the incorrect use of code markdown at that time.

In the end I agree with Philipp that making these edits could cause a lot of noise on the front page and potentially attract more votes to questions that might not need any more attention. If a post gets edited and attracts more downvotes the user that gets them might be a bit annoyed.